# How to find value of CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

I am trying to the find the value of CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, however upon running this code, i get an error below.

Unhandled exception at 0x74202C92 in Assignment1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cl::Error at memory location 0x0136F6E0.

New to OpenCL, hope to get some help here. Please advise me. Thanks a million!

```
            std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;    // available platforms
            std::vector<cl::Device> devices;        // devices available to a platform
            std::vector<cl::Device> compute_units;  // compute units available to a platform
            //size_t workgroup_size;                // workgroup size available to a platform
            std::string outputString;               // string for output
            unsigned int i, j;                      // counters

            std::cout << std::endl;
            cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
            std::cout << "Number of OpenCL platforms: " << platforms.size() << std::endl;

            // for each platform
            for (i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
            {
                std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
                // output platform index
                std::cout << "  Platform " << i << ":" << std::endl;

                // get maximum number of work group size available to the platform
                platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, &devices);

                std::cout << "\nNumber of Work Group Size available to platform " << i << ": " << sizeof(devices) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
            }
```

Comment: The first argument of getDevices should be of type cl_device_type... This function is used to initialize the vector with the available devices, according to the type of device that you want e.g. CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU or CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU.

Answer (score 0):

uncomment your workgroup_size.
and call the workgroup_size below in devices for eg:

```
//for all platforms 
for(int i = 0 ; i< platforms.size() ; i++){
//for all devices in the platform
for(int j = 0; j < devices.size() ; j++)
workgroup_size = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>();
                        cout << "\tMax Group Size: " << maxGroup << endl;
}
}
```